# Add product to a List - Flutter

Tags: flutter, api

I have a Gridview with products, I want to save those products to a list and the data should be saved in that list -

[image: 1]  [image: 2]

Data should look like this after saving the products to the list-

[image: 3]

Is there any way to do it? Data will be stored in API. Any help will be really helpful.

I attached the gridview code for the same-

```
GridView.builder(
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                          return Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  child: Align(
                                    child: GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: (){
                                        showModalBottomSheet(
                                            context: context,
                                            builder: (BuildContext context)  => Container(
                                              child: Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Column(
                                                    children: [
                                                      TextButton(
                                                        onPressed: (){
                                                          showModalBottomSheet(
                                   
                                                            context: context,
                                                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                                              return Container(
                                                                child: const Center(
                                                                  child: MenuListPage(),
                                                                ),
                                                              );
                                                            },
                                                          );
                                                        },
                                                        child: Row(
                                                          children: [
                                                            Image.asset("assets/images/AddToMenu.png",),
                                                            Text('Add to Menu',),
                                                          ],
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                     ],
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            )
                                        );
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                          child: Image.asset("assets/images/MenuIcon1.png")
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                        image: NetworkImage(
                                            snapshot.data!.data[index].thumb.toString()
                                        ),
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                    child: Text(snapshot.data!.data[index].prodName,),
                                )
                              ]);

                        },
                      );
```

Comment: pic 1's products,  add a Field named "category" in ur product class. then based on Category sort those products like pic 3's

Comment: Can you please elaborate?